# Optimizing assignments based on many variables

Tags: optimization, math

I was recently talking with someone in Resource Management and we discussed the problem of assigning developers to projects when there are many variables to consider (of possibly different weights), e.g.:

1. The developer's skills & the technology/domain of the project
2. The developer's travel preferences & the location of the project
3. The developer's *interests* and the nature of the project

The basic problem the RM person had to deal with on a regular basis was this: given X developers where each developers has a unique set of attributes/preferences, assign them to Y projects where each project has its own set of unique attributes/requirements.

It seems clear to me that this is a very mathematical problem; it reminds me of old *optimization* problems from algebra and/or calculus (I don't remember which) back in high school: you know, find the optimal dimensions for a container to hold the maximum volume given this amount of material—that sort of thing.

My question isn't about the math, but rather whether there are any software projects/libraries out there designed to address this kind of problem. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1):

*My question isn't about the math, but rather whether there are any software projects/libraries out there designed to address this kind of problem. Does anyone know of any?*

In my humble opinion, I think that this is putting the cart before the horse. You first need to figure out what problem you want to solve. Then, you can look for solutions.

For example, if you formulate the problem by assigning some kind of numerical compatibility score to every developer/project pair with the goal of maximizing the total sum of compatibility scores, then you have a maximum-weight matching problem which can be solved with the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). Conveniently, this algorithm is implemented as part of Google's [or-tools library](http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/).

On the other hand, let's say that you find that computing compatibility scores to be infeasible or unreasonable. Instead, let's say that each developer ranks all the projects from best to worst (e.g.: in terms of preference) and, similarly, each project ranks each developer from best to worst (e.g.: in terms of suitability to the project). In this case, you have an instance of the [Stable Marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage), which is solved by the Gale-Shapley algorithm. I don't have a pointer to an established library for G-S, but it's simple enough that it seems that lots of people just code their own.

Comment: Excellent resources, which I am just looking into now (thanks!).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are mathematical methods for solving a type of problem *which this problem can be shoehorned into*. It is the natural consequence of thinking of developers as "resources", like machine parts, largely interchangeable, their individuality easily reduced to simple numerical parameters. You can make up rules such as

```
The fitness value is equal to the subject skill parameter multiplied by the square root of the reliability index.
```

and never worry about them again. The same rules can be applied to different developers, different subjects, different scales of projects (with a SLOC scaling factor of, say, 1.5). No insight or real leadership is needed, the equations make everything precise and "assured".  The best thing about this approach is that when the resources fail to perform the way your equations say they should, you can just reduce their performance scores to make them fit. And if someone has already written the tool, then you don't even have to worry about the math.

(It is interesting to note that Resource Management people always seem to impose such metrics on others in an organization -- thereby making their own jobs easier-- and never on themselves...)